# Count of all File Ext in directory and subdirectories CMD

Tags: cmd

How would modify the CMD line below to include all subfolders?

```
cmd /c ">NUL (@for %I in (*) do @set /a ext[%~xI] += 1) & set ext["
```

Can I add an `/s` switch someplace in:

Desired output like below but would include all subfolders

```
ext[.pdf]=187
ext[.txt]=2
ext[.zip]=1
```

Thanks

Comment: The first question I have, based upon your batch file tag, is why are you invoking another instance of `cmd.exe`. Next I would advise that you open a `cmd.exe` window, type `for /?` and read its output. _You should notice an option to recurse subdirectories._

Comment: Thanks you both.  I had a number of bats that worked but I have to use it in an RDP where I am not an admin and cannot run bats, so I was left trying to figure out how do do from just CMD.  I think this is working: 
   `@(for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do @set /A ext[%~xI]+=1) & set ext[ >ListExt3.txt`

Comment: You can use the `/R`ecurse switch with `for`. As an example `for /R %i in (*) do set /a ext[%~xi]+=1`

Comment: The command line with `for /F` and `dir` is better as it considers also files with hidden attribute set like `desktop.ini` and others. `for /R` searches in the specified directory and all its subdirectories including those with hidden attribute set but it ignores files with hidden attribute set.

Comment: @TGM, as this has nothing to do with batch files, I have removed the invalid tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell is available. You can use this `cmd` command.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Group-Object -Property Extension | ForEach-Object { \"ext[$($_.Name)]=$($_.Count)\" }"
```

It is a bit less cryptic if you use a PowerShell console.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Group-Object -Property Extension | ForEach-Object {"ext[$($_.Name)]=$($_.Count)"}
```

And if this is not going into a .bat or .ps1 file script, you can use aliases and short parameters.

```
gci -re -file | group Extension | %{"ext[$($_.Name)]=$($_.Count)"}
```